# What does this mean: "In HTTP 1.1, all connections are considered persistent unless declared otherwise"?

Tags: networking, browser, http

In this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), it says the following:

> In HTTP 1.1, all connections are considered persistent unless declared
>   otherwise.

I think that this statement means is that when a client issues a request message, there is no need to include the following header in it: `Connection: keep-alive`. And if I want to declare otherwise, I would include the following header in it: `Connection: close`.

Am I correct?

Comment: yeah, that seems about right.

Answer (score 0):

That is correct. The default HTTP/1.1 behavior is to assume all connections should be kept open and it is up to the client to close it.

In comparison, when the `Connection: close` header is set, the Server will FIN the connection once it has finished sending all of the requested content, putting the server into TIME-WAIT state rather than the client.